# silicone injection molding - making a flexible ring

Tags: structural-engineering, chemical-engineering, industrial-engineering

I am working with silicone injection molding as a hobby and I am wanting to make a ring.

I have tried with 100% silicone and the results are a clear ring that is not quite the consistency I want. I would like to experiment with making it more or less elastic if possible, as well as different swirled colors.

How can I change the elasticity of a silicone ring and how can I introduce swirling colors into it as well?

I searched around for other existing things, and this silicone ring is close to what I want to make.

https://groovelife.co/products/silicone_ring_breathable_groove?variant=13528608580&gclid=CjwKEAiAkajDBRCRq8Czmdj-yFgSJADikZggxMT5d91MuDELqOKU6eFGvRvJWkAbHWH1_Gxu9of58RoC9oDw_wcB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using RTV silicone of the type used for prosthetics and animatronics then you can get a variety of grades with different mechanical properties, commonly rated by Shore Hardness.

You can also get additives known as 'deadeners' which create a more matte surface and reduce the slippery feel.

To create swirl colours you want to make up 2 or more batches of silicone of different colours mix in the catalyst , (pigments are available to add to clear silicone) and either mix them lightly once both area catalysed or inject  them into the mould at the same time. Different ratios and mixing methods will produce different results.